# Angular: ViewChild audio element as HTMLAudioElement?

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I'm trying to get an `audio` element inside a component. At first I was doing it the old fashioned way:

```
$player: HTMLAudioElement;
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.$player = document.getElementById('stream')
}
```

But I wanted to do it ***The Angular Way™*** so I figured I should use `@ViewChild`. But it returns an `ElementRef` and I have to repeatedly drill into the `nativeElement` property to actually act on the element and it just seems messier.

I would ***like*** to do something like this:

`@ViewChild('stream') $player: HTMLAudioElement;`

But that doesn't work.

Comment: When using view child to access the native DOM element it will be always wrapped inside ElementRef.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you associate a setter to `ViewChild`, you can initialize an `HTMLAudioElement` property in it, and use that property afterwards:

```
$player: HTMLAudioElement;

@ViewChild('stream') set playerRef(ref: ElementRef<HTMLAudioElement>) {
  this.$player = ref.nativeElement;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvpf28?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

---

Another way to make the access to the `ElementRef.nativeElement` less annoying is to define a getter property that returns the element:

```
@ViewChild('stream') playerRef: ElementRef<HTMLAudioElement>;

get $player(): HTMLAudioElement {
  return this.playerRef.nativeElement;
} 

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.$player);
  }
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yey3xe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.